# What's the best way to resize thousands images using paperclip and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a model with 6 paperclip photos (photo1, photo2, photo3, photo4, photo5 and photo6).

Because recently changes on design of site i need to resize all style on the six pictures. The styles are small, medium and large.

My idea is use a before filter method to do a Model.photo1.reprocess! and add a column to model table (for example "reprocess" as boolean) to check if it's was reprocessed or not.

This idea i think it's more eficcient than use a rake script to migrate all photos in one single migration with the next deploy.

**Product Controller**

```
before_filter :check_image_reprocess, :only => [:show]  

def check_image_reprocess
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  if @product.reprocess == false
    @product.photo.reprocess! unless @product.photo.nil?
    @product.photo2.reprocess! unless @product.photo2.nil?
    @product.photo3.reprocess! unless @product.photo3.nil?
    @product.photo4.reprocess! unless @product.photo4.nil?
    @product.photo5.reprocess! unless @product.photo5.nil?
    @product.photo6.reprocess! unless @product.photo6.nil?
    @product.update_attributes(:reprocess => true)
  end
end
```

Actually it's works, but if exists any comments about this or better suggestions, there will be very welcome :) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: sory, the title has an error, i meant thousand, not tousend. Thanks

Comment: Hi @jgunta. I realise this is an older question, and you're probably more familiar with Stack Overflow now... but you (and others) may want to know why this question got so many downvotes. Stack Overflow works best with specific, technical problems. Here you have asked us our opinions of whether there's a better implementation. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise - which is what Stack Overflow actually does best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way it's working perfectly after 1 week of testing !!

Enjoy